# The action menu is not getting closed even if I click somewhere on page, the menu remains open until I explicitly click on the Action button again

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
//This is dropdown component
const Dropdown: FC<any> = ({ list, item, title },props) => {
const isDisabled = item && item.users.length > 0 ? false : true;

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const toggleMenu = () => {
  setShow(!show);
};
return (
 <div>
 <Button
   title={title || "Action"}
   onClick={toggleMenu}
   iconName="downarrow"
   iconPosition="left"
   variant="outlined"
   color="primary" 
 />
 )
```

The action menu is not getting closed even if I click somewhere on page, the menu
remains open until I explicitly click on the Action button again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the action menu to close when you click anywhere on the page using `onClick` won't help it. Use `onBlur` and use it on the button as -

```
<Button
   title={title || "Action"}
   onClick={toggleMenu}
   onBlur={() => setShow(true)}
   iconName="downarrow"
   iconPosition="left"
   variant="outlined"
   color="primary" 
 />
```

Or alternatively, what you can do is -

- Create a reference to your outer div.
- Add event listener `mousedown` (or click) to the document whenever this component appears on screen (eg. mount) and also don’t forget to remove the event on unmount too.
- Inside the event (handleClick) `this.{Any ref name you give}.contains(e.target)` will return true if whatever you are clicking is inside the “node” ref.
- Now you have it, you can now do whatever you feel like, close the modal, close the dropdown menu list, anything is allowed.

The above 4 points were taken from the article - https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-react-component-5604830beb7f.